# Returning variables from a Vue.js directive

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-directives

Vue.js has a built-in directive called `v-for` which is used to literate  over list.

HTML code

```
<ul id="example-1">
  <li v-for="item in items">
    {{ item.message }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Script code

```
var example1 = new Vue({
  el: '#example-1',
  data: {
    items: [
      { message: 'Foo' },
      { message: 'Bar' }
    ]
  }
})
```

Here, by using the `v-for` directive, the elements in `items` array are returned as variables named `item`. Here, the variables returned by this `v-for` directive, can be used in the html DOM. How do I create such a custom directive which returns a variable to the html DOM?

Note: I did search for `v-for` directives source code in the [source code](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/) of vuejs, but could not find. Please help me to get this as I am very new to vuejs. Thank you.

**Edit**:

**What I currently have?**

There are 3 similar input groups for inputting 'First Name', 'Last Name'  and 'Address' respectively. Each input field has `label`, `state`, `disabled`, `value`, and `max` properties which are stored in a `inputOptions` array.

```
<!-- HMTL -->
<b-input-group :prepend="inputOptions.firstName.label">
    <b-form-input 
        :state="inputOptions.firstName.state" 
        v-model="inputOptions.firstName.value" 
        :disabled="inputOptions.firstName.disabled" 
        :maxlength="inputOptions.firstName.max"
        ></b-form-input>
</b-input-group>

<b-input-group :prepend="inputOptions.lastName.label">
    <b-form-input 
        :state="inputOptions.lastName.state" 
        v-model="inputOptions.lastName.value" 
        :disabled="inputOptions.lastName.disabled" 
        :maxlength="inputOptions.lastName.max"
        ></b-form-input>
</b-input-group>

<b-input-group :prepend="inputOptions.address.label">
    <b-form-input 
        :state="inputOptions.address.state" 
        v-model="inputOptions.address.value" 
        :disabled="inputOptions.address.disabled" 
        :maxlength="inputOptions.address.max"
        ></b-form-input>
</b-input-group>
```

//Script

```
inputOptions: {
            firstName: {
                label: 'First Name',
                state: true,
                value: 'Foo',
                disabled: true,
                max: 45
            },
            lastName: {
                label: 'Last Name',
                state: true,
                value: 'Bar',
                disabled: true,
                max: 45
            },
            address: {
                label: 'Address',
                state: false,
                value: 'Foo, Bar.',
                disabled: true,
                max: 255
            },
}
```

**What I needed to achieve**

For each input-group field, it is needed to provide the property names one by one. Assume that I have created a vue directive called `mydirective` and code is simplified as follows.

```
<!-- HMTL -->
<b-input-group v-mydirective="inputOptions.firstName as myProperty" :prepend="myProperty.label">
    <b-form-input 
        :state="myProperty.state" 
        v-model="myProperty.value" 
        :disabled="myProperty.disabled" 
        :maxlength="myProperty.max"
        ></b-form-input>
</b-input-group>

<b-input-group v-mydirective="inputOptions.lastName as myProperty" :prepend="myProperty.label">
    <b-form-input 
        :state="myProperty.state" 
        v-model="myProperty.value" 
        :disabled="myProperty.disabled" 
        :maxlength="myProperty.max"
        ></b-form-input>
</b-input-group>

<b-input-group v-mydirective="inputOptions.address as myProperty" :prepend="myProperty.label">
    <b-form-input 
        :state="myProperty.state" 
        v-model="myProperty.value" 
        :disabled="myProperty.disabled" 
        :maxlength="myProperty.max"
        ></b-form-input>
</b-input-group>
```

//Script

```
inputOptions: {
            firstName: {
                label: 'First Name',
                state: true,
                value: 'Foo',
                disabled: true,
                max: 45
            },
            lastName: {
                label: 'Last Name',
                state: true,
                value: 'Bar',
                disabled: true,
                max: 45
            },
            address: {
                label: 'Address',
                state: false,
                value: 'Foo, Bar.',
                disabled: true,
                max: 255
            },
}
```

Comment: `vue` code is usually compiled, i.e. it transform the document tree. (like [babel](https://babeljs.io/) )

Comment: you can of course write your own document parser, but why not try custom element first?

Comment: It's likely that you need a component (or component + directive combo) rather than the directive you described.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: I needed to pass a object which containing strings(key, value pairs) to a input-group component, and then string values inside that need to be changed according to the passed value. I don't need to change each string value manually

Comment: How can I use a component to do that? I have no idea.

Comment: We would need to see more of your code in order to provide some help.

Comment: @Rudy  I have added code for understanding more. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HTML**

In your template, iterate over the multiple `inputOptions` using `v-for` like:

```
<div id="app">
  <b-input-group v-for="option in inputOptions" :key="option.label" :option="option" />
</div>
```

**SCRIPT**

Create custom components for the group, input, and label, like:

```
Vue.component('b-label', {
  props: ['label'],
  template: '<div>{{ label }}</div>'
})

Vue.component('b-form-input', {
  props: ['state', 'value', 'disabled', 'maxlength'],
  template: '<input type="text" :value="value" />'
})

Vue.component('b-input-group', {
  props: ['option'],
  template:
  `<div>
    <b-label :label="option.label" />
    <b-form-input
        :state="option.state"
        v-model="option.value"
        :disabled="option.disabled"
        :maxlength="option.max" />
  </div>`
})
```

**FIDDLE**

[Here is a demo on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sh0ber/rvzmt5ks)

This is a basic example of how to use components.  Whatever transformations you need to do to the strings can be done in the associated components, via `computed` properties or methods.  You can see a demo by clicking the link where I use a `computed` property to transform the labels into lowercase.  That should be enough to get you going.